# AspNet Core Api Ef Core comes with extra related tables?

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-relationship

When I include the Categories table in the seller table with Ef Core, it comes with Product in the Category, I just want the category table to come. There is an overload of data. How can i solve it. Why does Products also appear in Category under Seller only? I just wrote .Include(Category), Products should not come??

The function I included

```
 public async Task<IResponse<Seller>> GetByIdAsyncR(int id)
        {
            var data = await _context.Sellers.Where(i => i.Id == id)
                .Include(i => i.Categories)
                .Include(i => i.AppUsers)
                .Include(i => i.Products)
                .Include(i => i.Orders)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (data != null)
                return new Response<Seller>(ResponseType.Success, data);
            return new Response<Seller>(ResponseType.NotFound, "Data bulunamadı");
        }
```

This is the result

```
{
  "email": "a1@a.com",
  "offers": [],
  "categories": [
    
      "name": "cat1",
      "description": "des1",
      "language": 0,
      "sellerId": 1,
      "imageId": null,
      "image": null,
      "products": [
        {
          "name": "pd 1",
          "language": 0,
          "description": "desdesdesdesdesdesdesdesdesdesdesdesdesdesdesdesdesdesdesdes1",
          "isStock": true,
          "isNew": true,
          "sellerId": 1,
          "categoryId": 1,
          "orderItems": [],
          "images": [],
          "cardItems": [],
          "menuProduct": [],
          "id": 1,
          "createdDate": "2023-02-13T01:52:17.5190827"
        }
      ],
      "id": 1,
      "createdDate": "2023-02-13T01:52:17.5190795"
    }
```

I don't understand why Seller->Category->Product is coming?
Shouldn't the Products under Category be empty?

I couldn't understand why Products is empty under Category. Shouldn't it be null?

Comment: It is documented behaviour. You have to use DTO classes and `Select`. Anyway `AsNoTracking()` may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a normal query result. `Include()` tells EF that you want to pull child records for processing. If you don't want child entities, don't use `Include`.

Like as Svyatoslav Danyliv said, you can add [`AsNoTracking`](https://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/entity_framework_and_asnotracking/) to your query:

```
var data = await _context.Sellers.Where(i => i.Id == id)
           .Include(i => i.Categories)
           .Include(i => i.AppUsers)
           .Include(i => i.Products)
           .Include(i => i.Orders)
           .AsNoTracking()
           .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

`AsNoTracking()` allows you to tell Entity Framework Core not to track the results of a query. This means that Entity Framework Core performs no additional processing or storage of the entities which are returned by the query.

If you want to use `Select()`, you can refer to the following code to feel the query results of `Select` more intuitively:

```
var data = await _context.Sellers.Where(i => i.Id == id)
          .Select(x => new {
                ParentRecord = x,
                ChildRecord = x.Categories,
                HasChildRecords = x.Categories.Any()
          })
          .Include(i => i.AppUsers)
          .Include(i => i.Products)
          .Include(i => i.Orders)
          .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Hope this can help you.